# How to have buttons permanently showing (even after activity change)

Tags: java, android, button

I am wondering if there is a way to have my 3 buttons shown permanently while I am changing activity. I have slide animations on the app when changing activity and it looks very odd that the buttons are sliding too. Below is what it looks like.[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use one activity and multiple fragments, instead of multiple activities. Have the buttons be part of the activity, and have the rest of the UI be in the fragments. Transition between the fragments.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the response. I will have a read up on these. Very helpful :)